# What plugin should I use to integrate TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, visualsvn

I have TortoiseSVN installed on my local machine just to improve my knowledge of subversion on some small personal projects. I downloaded and attempted to install VisualSVN to integrate TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio, but the VisualSVN installer threw an error--`There is a problem with this Windows installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.`

Are there any other programs/plugins that integrate TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio 2012 that are compatible with Windows 8?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the MSI you downloaded is corrupted and that's all.

Answer (score 4):

To integration VS with Subversion I use [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent) and this works well for me.

I've tried this setup on Windows 7 and Windows XP but not yet tried this on a Windows 8 machine.

Comment: +1 Plays well with SVN and VS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads) on Windows 8 for Visual Studio integration with Subversion.  It is separate and unrelated to TortoiseSVN.